# Why won't my World shader appear in rendered images but be visible in viewport?

Tags: world

I'm not using an image.  I created a starry night sky with several nodes, and it was appearing in rendered images but not anymore.  Small rendered image on the right has no starry night sky, node tree is below.
[image]

Comment: Hello, could you please share your file (remove the useless objects)? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Have you set _Film_ > _Transparent_ in the _Render Properties_ and maybe replaced the background with something else in the _Compositor_?

Comment: Film Transparent doesn't do anything helpful, and again I'm NOT using an image at all.  I'm using a noise texture for the stars and the default sky texture for fog and subtle lighting.  AS you can see in the attached image, all the nodes that create the World scene are right there - no background image is used.

Comment: I figured it out... early on I created a volume cube for fog and accidentally enabled the render/view icons and it was overshadowing the background in camera view.  Basically had nothing to do with the camera or renderer... smh...

Comment: @subc0der I know and see the node setup you did for the background, but that doesn't tell us anything about the rest of the scene. And as you now found out, _something_ had to be there or else it wouldn't have given that result. For example, if you would have shown the _Outliner_ in the screenshot, we might have spotted the enabled fog cube. So sorry for me guessing around, but you didn't provide enough information.